# How do I set an image on button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

`<%= button_to '+',{:controller=>"line_items",:action=>"create", :menu_id => line_item.menu_id},class: "imagePlus",:remote => true  %>`

`.imagePlus {background-image: url('..public/images/minus.jpg');}`

I want to set a background_image to this button.I have used the class having background_image, but didn't get expected result.

Comment: where is the image located, is it in assets/image folder or in public/image.

Comment: @John why not use link_to with block?

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:-

```
.imagePlus{background-image: url("/public/images/minus.jpg");}
```

Comment: check in the browser that the image is loading or not means the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *most likely* due to your calling of the background image.

More specifically, I believe you'll benefit from using the [`asset_url` helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html), with one of the [CSS prepropcessors (SCSS / SASS)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
.imagePlus  {
   background: {
       image: asset-url('minus.jpg');
   }
}
```

This is, of course, if your `button_to` syntax is correct

---

**Button Styling**

As per this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdgtocjt/), you should be able to see the background image on your button with your code (which means that if you get the CSS set up correctly, it should work).

You'll be better using `Mandeep`'s comment, and creating a styled [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) element. Either way, here's what I'd do for both types of input:

```
#Button
<%= button_to "+", line_items_path(line_item.menu_id), class: "imagePlus", remote: true %>

#Link
<%= link_to "+", line_items_path(line_item.menu_id), class: "imagePlus", method: :post, remote: true %>
```